# A Question about Measures of Subset of Cantor Space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ be a subset of cantor space $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ with positive measure. Is there a co-infinite set $b$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lbrace a\in A: a\cap b\in A\rbrace$ also has positive measure?

I can't get density to work here.

Comment: What measure are you endowing the Cantor space with?

Comment: @Dunnò000 The uniform measure obtained via extension from representation $r(\sigma)=2^{-|\sigma|}$